# マップの中心を一度だけ現在地にする方法

Tags: swift, xcode

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var theMap: MKMapView!

    //@IBOutlet weak var theLabel: UILabel!

    var manager:CLLocationManager!
    var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Setup our Location Manager
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //Setup our Map View
        theMap.delegate = self
        theMap.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
        theMap.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
        //theLabel.text = "\(locations[0])"
        myLocations.append(locations[0] as! CLLocation)

        let spanX = 0.001
        let spanY = 0.001
        var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: theMap.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
        theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)

        if (myLocations.count > 1){
            var sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
            var destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2

            let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
            let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
            var a = [c1, c2]
            var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
            theMap.addOverlay(polyline)

            //theMap.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.FollowWithHeading, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {

        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
            return polylineRenderer
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

上記のプログラムですが、中心がずっと現在地であるため画面を大きくすると、中心にしようとするためか画面の拡大ができません。
マップの中心に１度だけ現在地が表示されれば、あとは自由に拡大、縮小できるように変えたいと思っています。
わかる方がいましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

`didUpdateLocations`で

```
manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

を実行してGPSを止めればいいのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

```
locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject])
```

の中で

```
theMap.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone
```

を入れると解決するんじゃないでしょうか？

Comment: やってみましたが、変化はありませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

```
    var regionout:Bool = false

    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
    if(var regionout:Bool == false){        
    //theLabel.text = "\(locations[0])"
            myLocations.append(locations[0] as! CLLocation)

            let spanX = 0.001
            let spanY = 0.001
            var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: theMap.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
            theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)

            if (myLocations.count > 1){
                var sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
                var destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2

                let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
                let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
                var a = [c1, c2]
                var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
                theMap.addOverlay(polyline)

                //theMap.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.FollowWithHeading, 　　　animated: true)
            }
    regionout = true 
    }
}
```